# Building TensorFlow From Sources To Enable MPI

Tags: tensorflow, mpi, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to build TensorFlow from source to enable MPI for a project I am working on. However, when I run the `./configure` command, as part of the various questions asked to enable various things, MPI is not one of them.
Is there a different method to use TensorFlow with MPI or does TensorFlow now have MPI enabled by default?

Comment: Hi Jonathan, Kindly check you have an MPI implementation installed on your system. Common implementations include OpenMPI and MPICH. You need to install the MPI libraries and development headers.  make sure you have Bazel installed on your system. Basel is required for building Tensorflow. And additional dependencies might be required based on your system configuration.

Comment: Thanks @Sagar . I have Intel MPI. I think the issue is that Tensorflow now only has gRPC as communication backend. So I may have to use maybe Horovod if I want to use Tensorflow with MPI

Comment: Jonathan, If your are using Intel MPI, that Tensorflow’s default distributed training backend is gRPC, and it does not directly support intel MPI out of the box, However, as you  mentioned, Horovod is a great solution for using Tensorflow with MPI, including intel MPI. Horovod allows you to easily parallelize Tensorflow training across multiple nodes using MPI.
You can install  Horovod with Tensorflow and intel MPI.